# Why does an indefinite aggregate slide but a definite one does not?

Tags: compiler-errors, constraints, ada

This is one of those academic things I'd just like to understand better. (I have no justification for why one would write code like this.)

If you have code that starts with an indefinite type like

```
type Indef is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;
My_Indef : Indef (1..2) := (3=>0, 4=>0);
```

This will compile and the aggregate will slide; the  range will be 1..2

If instead you start with a definite type

```
type Def is array (1..2) of Integer;
My_Def : Def := (3=>0, 4=>0);
```

This will not compile without warning, nor run without a runtime error.  I don't see why the first sample will slide but the second will not.

Comment: I expect it's because 3 and 4 are outside the valid index range for a Def, but any integer is a valid index for an Indef. Thus the second example fails to create the aggregate, before it gets to the sliding stage.

Comment: Are you sure the problem with the second example is the aggregate?  Try `My_Def : Def := (3 => 0, 4 => 0);`.  I don't think `Def(1..2)` is legal here, because you're applying a constraint to a subtype that's already constrained.  Also try it without the aggregate, `My_Def : Def (1..2);`.  My suspicion is that this last is illegal.  I don't have time to try it right now.

Comment: P.S. Applying a constraint to a subtype that's already constrained isn't always illegal, but I believe it's illegal for array index constraints and discriminant constraints.

Comment: Sorry, the additional constraint was accidental  and not present in my code. I updated the question. I think on further experimentation I understand this better.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example is simply wrong.  As `Def` is a definite array type, you can't specify/change its constraints when you declare an object of that type.

If you try:

```
type Def is array (1..2) of Integer;
My_Def : Def := (3 => 0, 4 => 0);
```

it will compile, but fail at runtime, not because it can't slide, but because the initial constraints are out of range.

To see array sliding work for a definite array type, you could try:

```
J_Def : Def := (2 => 2) & (2 => 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure the second example will let him "see array sliding work"?  It looks to me like both My_Def and J_Def will get Constraint_Error.  Did you test it?

Comment: On reading the RM more carefully, I now think that neither one should raise Constraint_Error.  In any event, there's no way that one should succeed and the other fail, since the second example is equivalent to `J_Def : Def := (2 => 2, 3 => 1);`.

Comment: @Jacob Yes I realize it is wrong, the point of the question was to gain an understanding of why it was wrong and why the compiler decides to slide one syntax but not the other. I think the first comment to the post gave me the answer

Comment: @ajb Yes I tested it.  I'm not quite sure the second example really is equivalent to what you write.  I would have to read up on the array sliding rules, to check that.  If they are equivalent, we've found yet another bug in GNAT.

Comment: @ajb The second example given by Jacob will compile and work,The code  just creates two one element arrays and then concatenates them together to one two-element array. The RM addresses this case and says the "bound of the result is that of the index subytpe."  Doesn't really help me though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's equivalent.  The array concatenation creates an array whose bounds are 2..3 and whose elements are (2,1).  That follows from the rules about `&`; those rules don't care about the bounds of the eventual destination.  For initial expression assignment, the rules about whether the array slides or not look just at the bounds of the source array; they don't care whether this array was created by `&` or some other way.  I'm pretty sure that was the case in Ada 2005, and I don't think that any new build-in-place semantics would have altered this.

Comment: My understanding of the Reference Manual 4.5.3 (6 &7) indicates the  bounds will be 1..2.  Here's the full quote for both cases, I was quoting  part of item 6 above.    
    6 • If the ultimate ancestor of the array type was defined by a constrained_array_definition, then the lower bound of the result is that of the index subtype;
    7 • If the ultimate ancestor of the array type was defined by an unconstrained_array_definition, then the lower bound of the result is that of the left operand.

Comment: OK, I actually wasn't aware of that rule.  So in this example, you're right, the bounds of the result of `&` are 1..2.  I don't think it matters in this case, though.  Even if the bounds were something different, as long as the length is 2, the initial expression will be converted to the subtype whose bounds are 1..2, and this conversion allows sliding (3.3.1(17), 4.6(37-39)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the comments. They led me to a deeper understanding and I think the answer.  If instead I had created two definite types that differ only in that one has a range of 1..2 and one with a range of 3..4 then I can assign them to each other and they will slide.  **BUT** I have to cast the right hand side to be of the type of the left hand side first, because they are different types. That, I think, is the difference between my two examples in the question.

The aggregate I specify in the second example would need to create an array of some anonymous type  with the aggregate's range and then cast it to a type of `Def. Instead it creates an array of type`Def and warns me the aggregate is out 
range and I have a constraint error in my future.

In the first example I'm just creating two arrays of type Indef with different ranges and the compiler is sliding the aggregate one over the left hand side.

Given the emphasis on type safety I can see now why the compiler is willing to do the first but not the second. Ada doesn't do auto casting anywhere else and certainly shouldn't start here.

For clarity here's a screenshot of the sample project with the code and compiler feedback.

[image]

Comment: I still think the compiler is wrong.  If it's saying you're about to get an exception in the second example, then it's a compiler bug.  Please don't try too hard to gain any deeper understanding of Ada from this example.

Comment: I added a screenshot so that the actual compiler output can be seen.

Comment: Good, now we have a screenshot that demonstrates that the compiler is wrong.